# Open API 3.0 using openapi-generator-maven-plugin not showing any swagger doc

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, springfox

Facing this issue with Open API 3.0, I am generating the code using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`. I am able to generate the code as well. Code is there in the finally generated Jar of Spring boot as well. But Some how I am not able to see the swagger-doc. All I see is this pop-up with this description

```
Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:
```

I tried setting up the `baseUrl` property, like this

```
baseUrl=http://localhost:8080/api
```

This isn't working, generated Config & controller has following code.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:swagger-ui.html";
    }
}
```

Following is configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class OpenAPIDocumentationConfig {

    ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("School REST API")
            .description("School  REST API")
            .license("ABC")
            .licenseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .contact(new Contact("","", "xyz@abc.com"))
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket customImplementation(ServletContext servletContext, @Value("${openapi.schoolRest.base-path:}") String basePath) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.school.rest.generated.controllers"))
                    .build()
                .pathProvider(new BasePathAwareRelativePathProvider(servletContext, basePath))
                .directModelSubstitute(java.time.LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
                .directModelSubstitute(java.time.OffsetDateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
                .genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    class BasePathAwareRelativePathProvider extends RelativePathProvider {
        private String basePath;

        public BasePathAwareRelativePathProvider(ServletContext servletContext, String basePath) {
            super(servletContext);
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }

        @Override
        protected String applicationPath() {
            return  Paths.removeAdjacentForwardSlashes(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(super.applicationPath()).path(basePath).build().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public String getOperationPath(String operationPath) {
            UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/");
            return Paths.removeAdjacentForwardSlashes(
                    uriComponentsBuilder.path(operationPath.replaceFirst("^" + basePath, "")).build().toString());
        }
    }

}
```

I have also removed the `springfox` & `swagger` related jars from my project.

Please advice.

Comment: i spent the day on my own version of almost exactly this. did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Yes, at the end we found out that the existing spring version isn't compatible with some of the features required to generate OpenAPI 3.0, so we upgraded our spring version and everything started working.